# I need to swap any two telephone numbers in the Outlook ContactItem object

Tags: vba, outlook, pass-by-reference

I writing some code to tidy up my contact list in Outlook.

Over the years I've stored 'extra' telephone numbers in various fields, and now I want to move them around.

Specifically when I recognise a non-mobile number in a mobile field and a mobile number in a non-mobile field then I want to swap them.

However, the code below doesn't work; it doesn't error but the telephone numbers are unchanged once the swap routine returns.

I think because either my use of ByRef is incorrect or class properties can't be passed by reference or class string properties behave in strange ways that I cannot fathom.

I've tried both PriortySwitch Arg1 Arg2 Arg3 and Call PrioritySwitch(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3)

Even if someone can confirm that it can't be done at least I will stop wasting time trying to puzzle it out.

```
Sub Whatever
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim Contacts As Items
  Dim Contact As ContactItem

  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  'use the default folder
  Set Contacts = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items.Restrict("[MessageClass]='IPM.Contact'")

  'do whatever
  On Error GoTo WTF

  For Each Item In Contacts
    If Item.Class = olContact Then
      Set Contact = Item
      With Contact
        ' Call SetCategories(Contact)
        '.MobileTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.MobileTelephoneNumber)
        '.AssistantTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.AssistantTelephoneNumber)
        '.Business2TelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.Business2TelephoneNumber)
        '.BusinessFaxNumber = FormatTel(.BusinessFaxNumber)
        '.BusinessTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.BusinessTelephoneNumber)
        '.CallbackTelephoneNumber = Format(.CallbackTelephoneNumber)
        '.CarTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.CarTelephoneNumber)
        '.CompanyMainTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.CompanyMainTelephoneNumber)
        '.Home2TelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.Home2TelephoneNumber)
        '.HomeFaxNumber = FormatTel(.HomeFaxNumber)
        '.HomeTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.HomeTelephoneNumber)
        '.OtherFaxNumber = FormatTel(.OtherFaxNumber)
        '.OtherTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.OtherTelephoneNumber)
        '.PagerNumber = FormatTel(.PagerNumber)
        '.PrimaryTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.PrimaryTelephoneNumber)
        '.RadioTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.RadioTelephoneNumber)
        '.TTYTDDTelephoneNumber = FormatTel(.TTYTDDTelephoneNumber)

        ' prioritise
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .BusinessTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .Business2TelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .BusinessFaxNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .CompanyMainTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .PrimaryTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .AssistantTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .CallbackTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .CarTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .CompanyMainTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .Home2TelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .HomeTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .OtherTelephoneNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .PagerNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .HomeFaxNumber, True
        PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .OtherFaxNumber, True

        If Not .Saved Then .Save
      End With
    End If
  Next
  Exit Sub
  WTF:
    Debug.Print Contact
End Sub

Sub PrioritySwitch(ByRef Tel1 As String, ByRef Tel2 As String, mobileOnly As Boolean)
  Dim t1 As String
  Dim switchTel As Boolean

  switchTel = False

  'Logic code goes here
  switchTel = True

  If switchTel Then
    t1 = Tel1
    Tel1 = Tel2
    Tel2 = t1
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this...

> ```
> With Contact
>     '...
>     PrioritySwitch .MobileTelephoneNumber, .BusinessTelephoneNumber, True
> ```

...you're calling a ***property*** of the `Contact` object.  This returns the phone number to an internal stack variable.  That internal stack variable is what is being passed `ByRef` to your `PrioritySwitch` `Sub`.  Once it returns, the stack variables are simply discarded because you aren't assigning them to anything.  This is equivalent to...

```
Dim stackVar1 As String
stackVar1 = Contact.MobileTelephoneNumber
Dim stackVar2 As String
stackVar2 = Contact.BusinessTelephoneNumber
PrioritySwitch stackVar1, stackVar2, True
'...and then stackVar1 and stackVar2 disappear...
```

`ByRef` can't just magically hook up a procedure to a property like that - envision what they would look like in a VBA class, because that is pretty close to what is going on when you use the property of a COM object.

```
Public Property Let MobileTelephoneNumber(number As String)
    'Frobs whatever Outlook does to store the number.
End Property

Public Property Get MobileTelephoneNumber() As String
    'Frobs whatever Outlook does to retrieve the number.
End Property
```

---

That said, you can do something similar using the `CallByName` function, and just call the properties directly in your `Sub`:

```
Public Sub PrioritySwitch(target As ContactItem, propertyOne As String, _
                          propertyTwo As String, mobileOnly As Boolean)
    Tel1 = CallByName(target, propertyOne, VbGet)
    Tel2 = CallByName(target, propertyTwo, VbGet)

    '...code that sets switchTel

    If switchTel Then
      CallByName target, propertyOne, VbLet, Tel2
      CallByName target, propertyTwo, VbLet, Tel1
    End If
End Sub
```

Then your calling code would look more like this (without the `With` block - unless you have more work to do with `Contact`):

```
    ' prioritise
    PrioritySwitch Contact, "MobileTelephoneNumber", "BusinessTelephoneNumber", True
    PrioritySwitch Contact, "MobileTelephoneNumber", "Business2TelephoneNumber", True
    PrioritySwitch Contact, "MobileTelephoneNumber", "BusinessFaxNumber", True
    PrioritySwitch Contact, "MobileTelephoneNumber", "CompanyMainTelephoneNumber", True
    ' etc...
```